# numpy array module is not defined

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to learn how numpy arrays works in python to accomplish some tasks , but I encountered a problem at a very early basic level .

I tried this very simple script :

```
import numpy
v = array([1,2,3,4])
type(v)
```

but I got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Al-Hammad\Desktop\Test Sample\whatever.py", line 5, in <module>
    v = array([1,2,3,4])
NameError: name 'array' is not defined

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

I have tried the following solutions but None of them worked out the problem.

1.One might say that I don't have numpy installed , I tried this and it's already there:

```
try: import 
numpy 
print("Numpy is already there !") 
except ImportError: p
rint("Numpy is not installed")

Numpy is already there !
Tool completed successfully
```

2.The file name is whatever.py , so it's not a matter of duplicate module's names as some threads suggests.

3.numpy is written correctly , so it's not a syntax error or a typo !!

4.I tried this also:

```
import numpy
import array 
from array import array
v = numpy.array([1,2,3,4])

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Al-Hammad\Desktop\Test Sample\whatever.py", line 6, in v = numpy.array([1,2,3,4]) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'array'
Tool completed with exit code 1
```

What am I doing wrong here ? Any help would be appreciated .

**Edit:**

@Ffisegydd...Python can see the numpy package , but it can't access it's contents,when I looked into programs and features in the control panel it wasn't there , but it's contents resides in the site_packages folder where python installed !!

Could it have been uninstalled in any way during system update ?

Comment: You should do a refresher on Python names and namespaces; if you do `import numpy` you would never automatically get access to any names other than `numpy`. This is nothing to do with numpy itself, but a basic principle of Python.

Comment: the last code while a bit of a  mess should not cause any error

Comment: @Daniel Roseman ... How can I refresh the namespace , or as referred by some other threads as kernel cleanup ?!

Comment: @Padraic... if so , then why it throws that error ? can you explain that to me please :)

Comment: Do you by any chance have a file called numpy.py in your local directory?

Comment: @Ffisegydd...Do you mean the python shell ?

Comment: @DanielRoseman...No , I don't have such file in the working directory !!

Comment: I suspect that you have a file called `numpy.py` **somewhere** on your path and it's being confused for the real numpy module. Can you do `import numpy; print(numpy.__file__)` ?

Comment: I did , that's what I got : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Al-Hammad\Desktop\Test Sample\whatever.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(numpy.__file__)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'

Comment: @Ffisegydd...It's driving me crazy ... if the numpy module is seen by the python environment ,then how come I can't use it's classes or even see where it resides , and what version does it have !!!

Comment: At this point the only thing I can suggest is uninstalling and re-installing it. If you installed it over a year ago then it's due an upgrade anyway, so might as well do it now. Let us know if that doesn't fix it. **EDIT: Can you do `print(numpy)` after importing it somewhere for us?**

Comment: @Ffisegydd...I did typed print(numpy) after importing and the tool completed successfully saying <module 'numpy' (namespace)> !! O.o

Comment: Don't `import array`.  There is an `array` module which is unrelated to `numpy`.  You don't want that.

Comment: @hpaulj...Even when I don't import array , and refer to it as numpy.array([...]) it doesn't work either , it says module object has no attribute 'array' :/

Answer (score 3):

If you've imported numpy with `import numpy` then it's in the `numpy` namespace, as such you need to use `numpy.array` rather than `array`.

Alternatively you could do `from numpy import array` to place `array` in your global namespace, but remember that this would not import any of the other `numpy` objects/functions.

Typically, when working with numpy, you would actually use `import numpy as np` to shorten the name a bit.

```
import numpy as np

print(np.array([1,2,3]))
# [1 2 3]
```

Comment: a +1 but the last code should not throw any error, the OP imported numpy and used `numpy.array`

Comment: @Ffisegydd... I tried what you suggested , and it gave me this : AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'array'

Comment: @Ffisegydd... I'm running it using Wing IDE , is this might be the cause ?! :O

Comment: @Ffisegydd...Yes I did , it gave me this : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'array'

Comment: @Ffisegydd... I installed it from official release version , I don't recall the source exactly , that was a year ago .

Comment: if **your** program is named `numpy.py` then it can also cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work this out be **reinstalling** numpy , and everything works just as expected ... cheers :D